# WPF / WCF Push Notification

Tags: wcf, notifications

Does .NET 3.5 (WCF, or other) offer any type of push notification service?

---

I have a server and a client. I want a service to run on the server and if x happens then push a notification to the client. I don't want to pull the server every x minutes to gather the information.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you are looking for? Technically, .Net events are a push notification service but I figure that's not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your question couldn't be any more general, but I'm going to take a guess and suggest you look at [WCF callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044174/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-use-wcf-callbacks).

I doubt your question relates to WPF or even WF, but you will need to elaborate if you think otherwise.

Comment: I have a server and a client. I want a service to run on the server and if x happens then push a notification to the client. I don't want to pull the server every x minutes to gather the information.

Comment: Looking into that now. Thanks Kent.

Comment: Im trying to click the link, but it no longer works in 2016.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use any call backs.
You can use MSMQ with WCF.
You can use the attached example I have made.
If you sent it to be a public push server - i.e available via WebService - you will have to add a webservice that will use the MSMQ.
The problem is that you will need to have an IIS installed on both the server and the client.
If you use it internally then MSMQ will be enough.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WcfMsmqServerPush.aspx

Comment: Having to install IIS on all clients is hardly ever reasonable