# Producer/Consumer pattern in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, .net-4.5

I have a `tcp` WCF service that is meant to calculate certain prices and put them into a queue for the client to pick up and to display.

The first thing that came to my mind was the `Producer/Consumer` pattern.  The WCF Service produces the prices and puts them into a queue. The client would then consume any workitems ready in the queue.

Looking at [Albahari's BlockingCollection example](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT), how he explains producer/Consumer pattern, I can't get my head around it.

```
var pcQ = new PCQueue (1);
Task task = pcQ.EnqueueTask (() => Console.WriteLine ("Easy!"));
```

If I run this on the `WCF service` I have put a task in the queue to be processed, fair enough. But once the task is finished on the service side, how do I push the price to the client automatically? or is that not something I could do with a `tcp` WCF service?

Comment: I don't have personal experience in WCF, so I'll limit this to a comment/link, but look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For your problem I can think in two solutions:

The First: in your Task you put the push logic to send the result in your active connection, but... you have to build all the push environment for that.

The second: when you finish your task you could put the result in another endpoint to the client and, in the client, you build a logic to ask to the server "did you finished my task? What´s the answer?"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to be making use of WCF callbacks.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044174/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-use-wcf-callbacks) is a question that might help guide you to what you want to do.

The producer/consumer pattern is valid.  The WCF callback is just an implementation detail in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately this isn't exactly what I was thinking of. In his example he calls  `proxy.DoSomething();` and then the server calls back. Thats not a push notification, its a callback on a pull. I have the feeling thats impossible with tcp. I might have to read up that MSMQ article.

Comment: The client need only call `Connect()` in a one way operation.  The server can then simply store the context and then when which ever thread is handling the queue pulls off a new price the WCF services can take that price and call back on the client context.  My point was that `CallbackContract` is how you can do this not specifically the implementation in the link.  Yes reentrant calls would not work in your case.  It's no different then a chat program really.