# CallBack Contract and Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, wcf-callbacks

I have my service on a web site. I try to run this example, first just the server part:
:[What steps do I need to take to use WCF Callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044174/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-use-wcf-callbacks)

But I get this message: "Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it."

The Web.config file, doesn't have definitions such 'BasicHttpBinding'. It only has more general defitions. Do i have to add lines to it, or there is a more simple way. Many thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `BasicHttpBinding` is the default binding for `http` services in WCF - if you don't specify something else in the code or the config, you will get `BasicHttpBinding` for any client connecting to your service over `http`.  Note that in the example you linked to is using `NetTCP`, which *does* support duplex.  I suggest trying the whole example first, to see if you can get it to run, rather than piecemeal.

Comment: but the server depends on the client? and what if server is started first?

Comment: @user3344394 - Have you tried running the complete, posted example?  The service has to be running for the client to connect.   The service does not depend on the client, outside of needing a client to make the callback to.

Comment: it's not so clear in the example what methods belong to the client. MyContractClient  and  MyCallbackClient  and Program should be on the client side?

Comment: In the example, `MyContractClient` is used by the client to invoke operations which the service will execute. `MyCallbackClient` is implemented on the client to handle callbacks from the service. To further clear things up, the `IMyContract` lists the methods the client may invoke and `IMyContractCallback` lists the methods the service may invoke.

Comment: it's not possible to attach the service reference to the client: I get this error: contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.

Comment: @user3344394 - `BasicHttpBinding` does not support duplex.  To do this over HTTP, you would use `DualWsHttpBinding`.  Have you done as I suggested yesterday and tried to build and run the *entire* example?  It looks like your somewhat new to WCF and you're attempting to pick and choose parts of code without understanding the whole.  While you can do that and learn, it'll be a long and frustrating path, especially in WCF.